# Tkinter，Mouse wheel binding scroll bar

Tags: tkinter, scrollbar

I want scroll bar working when there are a lot of data,but when there is a few data, it's not scrolling.

```py
from tkinter import *

def on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-1*(int(event.delta/120)), "units")

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

canvas = Canvas(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel)

for i in range(10):
    label = Label(canvas, text="Label " + str(i))
    canvas.create_window(0, i*20, anchor=NW, window=label)

canvas.update_idletasks()
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

I want scroll bar working when there are a lot of data, but when there is a few data, it's not scrolling. How to make it?

Comment: What OS are you using? I believe that `<MouseWheel>` is only for Windows.

Comment: Do you want that *"when there is a few data, it __should not__ scroll"* actually?

Comment: Set to 100 `root.geometry('400x100'`) instead of 300